# How to Avoid execution of associated executable in C# setup project during installation

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005

I have a C# setup project which is associated with another C# project. The 'custom action' includes the primary output of the associated project. When I install this setup, during installation the associated project is executed twice (during uninstall the exe gets executed once). I am guessing that it could be due to some property setting. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do this all the time, nothing ever runs twice (VS2010 though). Is the project a custom installer with a class that inherits from `Installer`?

Comment: No, the project is not a custim installer

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the problem. I had added the primary output of associated project as custom action. It is sufficient to add the primary output of associated project to 'File System' (primary output of associated project shall be copied to TARGETDIR during installation). If the associated project has custom action then its primary output should be added to 'Custom action'. {twice during installation: Install and rollback. once during uninstall: uninstall}.